# Form state cache breaks dependency injection

Tags: 8, forms, dependency-injection

I have a class that `extends FormBase` and there are 6 services that are injected into the class via Dependency Injection (DI). My problem is when I submit the form it says to a class property that normally should be injected, it's `NULL` and can't be called the `load()` function on `NULL`. However when I debug, I clearly see all the dependencies are injected to the class and saved to the properties, but until the execution reaches the validation/submit function somehow it became all property to `NULL`. Why does this happen? How can I use DI in the form validation/submit phase? I'm really thinking if this class is not a deserialized cached version...
Extra info this form also has an ajax function where the DI works fine.

I went a bit deeper into the system, after the classfinder creates my form with the injected things and saved into this place: `$form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']`, I found it out the problem is the cache. (`/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormCache.php:149`)

```
  protected function loadCachedFormState($form_build_id, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($stored_form_state = $this->keyValueExpirableFactory->get('form_state')->get($form_build_id)) {
      // Re-populate $form_state for subsequent rebuilds.
      $form_state->setFormState($stored_form_state);

      // If the original form is contained in include files, load the files.
      // @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface::loadInclude()
      $build_info = $form_state->getBuildInfo();
```

The system loads the formstate from the cache with the following lines, the `$stored_form_state` contains the cached state, without any dependencies, and the `$form_state->setFormState($stored_form_state);` line overwrites my formstate which contains the right properties with the DI classes... And that's a problem.

Comment: Hey hey, welcome back. :) Without seeing your code we probably can't tell you much more then there's in the docs. See [Dependency Injection for a Form](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form).

Comment: @leymannx Hey, I exactly using like that. And as I said it works except on final submit, and it turns out the Drupal cache is faulty...

Comment: Sounds like a core bug to me. But still, we didn't see your code. So, hard to tell, hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha, I've fount it finally. The problem was the properties were private. And the serialization trait wasn't able to save the values and when it loaded back it became null.

Comment: Thank you, really saved me a lot of time here!

Comment: And if I don't miss it, the property can be protected or public, but not private because it can't see/use the trait the private properties.